# How do I sort elements in a hash table in alphabetical order?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

How do I sort hash table elements alphabetically? For example, my elements are:

```
cijfercode, Zweeds, Doorloper, Kruizword, Crypto, Woordzoker
```

**edit**: I also got a solution for sorting the hashtable elements. Here is the solution:

```
java.util.Vector vec = new java.util.Vector(hashtableList.keySet());
Collections.sort(vec);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.util.Vector vec =new java.util.Vector(hashtableList.keySet()); 
Collections.sort(vec);
```

Answer (score 9):

If these "elements" are *keys* you can store them in a `TreeMap`, which will produce a consistent order based on the *natural ordering* of the keys. Note you don't need to do much except create a new map with the old map passed to the constructor:

```
Map<String,?> map = ?
Map<String,?> orderedMap = new TreeMap<String,?>(map);
```

Then, iterate like normal:

```
for(String key : orderedMap.keys()){

}
```

If your "elements" are *values*, then you can insert them as keys into a `TreeMap` keeping track of the original keys, read the sorted order of values as before (basically creating an inverted index):

```
Map<?,String> map = ?
Map<String,List<?>> orderedVals = new TreeMap<String,List<?>>();
for(Entry<?,String> map : map.entrySet()){
    List<?> keys = orderedVals.get(map.getValue());
    if(keys == null){
        keys = new ArrayList<?>();
        orderedVals.put(map.getValue(), keys);
    }
    keys.add(map.getKey());
}

// now orderedVals has keys in sorted order
for(String val : orderedVals.keys()){

}
```

Of course, if you're not actually using anything related to the fact these things are in a "hashtable" (I read this as something implementing `Map`), then you can load up a `List` of your choosing, and sort it:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(map.values()); // or use map.keys()
Collections.sort(list);
```

If you're not happy with the default sort order for `String`, feel free to write your own comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String left, String right){
        return // your impl
    }
});
```

`compare` must return a negative integer when the `left` comes first, 0 if `left` and `right` are the same, and  a positive integer if `right` comes first.

Comment: +1 Not a bad answer, though in the case of the inverted map I'd rather just use Guava's `SortedSetMultimap` instead. (I'll post an entry expressing the idea in a minute.)

Comment: actullly my problem is i have to parsed these values Cijfercode, Crypto Doorloper Kruizword Woordzoker Zweeds from xml.but in xml they are in the alphabetical order same as above.but while using hashtable to retrive values it becomes the order Cijfercode, Doorloper Woordzoker Zweeds Kruizword Crypto why is is happening?

Comment: @chinchu: `HashMap` does not have any iteration ordering guarantees. If you want one, you have two choices: `TreeMap` (natural or comparator-based order) and `LinkedHashMap` (insertion order).

Answer (score 5):

Mark Elliot's idea is correct. I don't like the whole `Map<?, List<?>>` idea though; I've been far too spoilt on [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). So here's a Guava version of the same idea:

```
SortedSetMultimap<String, ?> sorted = Multimaps.invertFrom(
        Multimaps.forMap(map), TreeMultimap.create());
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : sorted.entries()) {
    // ...
}
```

This is, like, a third of the size of Mark's code. :-)

Comment: So, to be fair, guava is at least a 100KB include, my code stuffed somewhere as `invertMap` is 321B, or about 3 *orders of magnitude* more concise :), +1, that's much more readable.

Comment: @chinchu: 1. Don't use `Vector`! If you must, use `ArrayList` instead. 2. I'd still, in most (>95%) cases, prefer to use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` if sorted keys are desirable.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply .Could you plesae tell is there any problems while using vector.(is it take more time for execution? )

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.19588.13 for an interesting discussion on this.

Consider http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html too.

Comment: actullly my problem is i have to parsed these values Cijfercode, Crypto Doorloper Kruizword Woordzoker Zweeds from xml.but in xml they are in the alphabetical order same as above.but while using hashtable to retrive values it becomes the order Cijfercode, Doorloper Woordzoker Zweeds Kruizword Crypto why is is happening?

Comment: Hi every one. i got a solution for sorting the hashtable elements .Here is the solution
 java.util.Vector vec =new java.util.Vector(hashtableList.keySet()); 
Collections.sort(vec);